# Can't get rsync options right

Tags: fedora, rsync

I am running this command as bash script:

```
rsync -avz -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /srv/system/scripts/test.txt server@hidden:/home/server/serverscripts/mounts/digitalocean
```

And this is the output:

```
# ./rsync
sending incremental file list
rsync: link_stat "/srv/system/scripts/StrictHostKeyChecking=no" failed: No such file or directory (2)

sent 49 bytes  received 12 bytes  40.67 bytes/sec
total size is 15  speedup is 0.25
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.0]
```

I believe the problem is the order of the options in the command but I can't find a way to fix it. The test file is sent anyway, but I believe StrictHostKeyChecking isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try quoting your ssh command:

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" /srv/system/scripts/test.txt server@hidden:/home/server/serverscripts/mounts/digitalocean
```